# EF6 - Using Copied Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

Environment:
EF6 - code first - C#, ASP.NET.

I copied my existing database (call it `Db1`) that was generated by EF6 with another name - `Db2`.

By modifying `web.config`'s connection string to `Db2`, it started working with `DB2`, & has been working fine for the last 6 months.

Problem:
Today, my `update-database -script` is showing a `create table` for all the tables in the database, whereas all the table exists and there have been no pending changes.

Just for testing: if I change my `web.config` connection string back to `DB1`, it shows no pending changes which is the correct behavior.

What could have gone wrong?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Check the Migrations History table (__MigrationsHistory) )in the two databases and ensure these are synchronized.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My _MigrationsHistory table in DB2 is blank whereas in DB1 it has all the Migrations. In the past I ran update-database successfully on my DB2 multiple times but never checked this table. what is a good next step to resolve this issue?

Comment: I have a database in Test that was generated by EF6. If I need to copy this database to UAT and production, can I simply include _MigrationsHistory table while copying. By doing this I will be at the same point in time with the databases in all 3 locations?

Comment: I would suspect that if you backup and restore all tables including the Migrations ones, then EF would treat them identically with no surprises. I personally opt to manage the DB manually rather than migrations, but others may have an explanation why past runs might have either skipped migrations or been satisfied the DB was already up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks for the answer StevePy What is the reason of not being in favor of migrations? Do you know if there will be any issues later if I copy _MigrationsHistory table as well? @StevePy

Comment: Personally I prefer to control the schema explicitly, and I'm often working with DBAs that want to maintain oversight on schema decisions rather than relying on a development library like EF "tinkering" with the database schema. Migrations are great for getting a new system DB up and running quickly, but as a system matures then schema updates become a less spontaneous change.